# Printing command line arguments after removing duplicates using dynamic memory allocation gives a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPresent(char *array[], char *string, int dimension) {
  for (int i=0; i<dimension; i++) {
    if (strcmp(array[i], string) != 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int dim = 0;
  char **without_duplicates = malloc(dim * sizeof(char *));
  for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    if (!isPresent(without_duplicates, argv[i], dim)) {
      realloc(without_duplicates, (dim + 1) * sizeof(char *));
      without_duplicates[dim] = malloc((strlen(argv[i]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(without_duplicates[dim], argv[i]);
      printf("%s\n", without_duplicates[dim]);
      dim++;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", "Not duplicated arguments:");
  for (int i=0; i<dim; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", without_duplicates[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I execute the code: `./a.out rome turin rome milan venice milan florence`.
But obtain segmentation fault error.

I tried to debug the code and it works until a certain point.
For example it copies `rome`, `turin`, discards `rome`, copies `milan`, but not `venice` and the other cities.

If it works for some cities why not with the others?
The program has an unexpected behavior, and crashes at different points with different arguments.

I don't know the number of arguments and their length, so the new array without the duplicates must be allocated dynamically.

Comment: Start by reading the documentation of [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). You're not using it correctly. That return value is there for a reason. The linked reference includes samples, none of which ignore the return value, and that isn't by accident.

Comment: Also read more about [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), it's implementation-defined if allocating zero amount of bytes return a non-null pointer or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you are not assigning the return value of realloc to any variable

```
realloc(without_duplicates, (dim + 1) * sizeof(char *));
```

According to **[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)**:

> **On success, returns the pointer to the beginning of newly allocated memory.** The returned pointer must be deallocated with `free()`or `realloc()`. The original pointer ptr is invalidated and any access to it is undefined behavior (even if reallocation was in-place).
>
> **On failure, returns a null pointer.** The original pointer ptr remains valid and may need to be deallocated with `free()` or `realloc()`.

Try doing something like

```
char** temp = realloc(without_duplicates, (dim + 1) * sizeof(char *));

if(temp != NULL) {
    without_duplicates = temp
}
else {
    //handle the unsuccessful allocation
}
```

Note: Similarly you need to check for `malloc()` whether the memory allocation was successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I also allowed myself to remove some useless statements within your code, hope you dont mind

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPresent(char *array[], char *string, int dimension) 
{
  for (int i=0; i<dimension; i++) 
  {
    if (strcmp(array[i], string) == 0)
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  int dim = 0;
  char ** without_duplicates = malloc(dim * sizeof(char *));

  for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) 
  {
    if (!isPresent(without_duplicates, argv[i], dim)) 
    {
      without_duplicates = realloc(without_duplicates, (dim + 1) * sizeof(char *));
      without_duplicates[dim] = malloc((strlen(argv[i]) + 1) * sizeof(char));

      strcpy(without_duplicates[dim], argv[i]);
      dim++;
    } 
  }

  printf("%s\n", "Not duplicated arguments:");

  for (int i=0; i<dim; i++) 
  {
    printf("%s\n", without_duplicates[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Your problem was simply not getting the return value out of realloc function,
C is not what one may consider as a high-level programming language... If reallocating some memory, the variable storing that address must be aware of the new address of the new allocated memory hence you must store it:

```
 without_duplicates = realloc(without_duplicates, (dim + 1) * sizeof(char *));
```

This caused segmentation fault because before storing the new allocated address you simply jumped to an address that does not exist within the context of your process and attempt store some data in it, that in result causes segmentation fault

Comment: Thanks also to you for your suggestions and code improvements.

Comment: What happens when malloc fails? @Cherubim you'd also be assigned with a NULL ptr and have a segmentation fault when trying to strcpy into it... so? There are many other things wrong within this program, I'm not trying to teach this guy how to code correctly, just how to periodically fix his current problem

Comment: I understand yet I disagree with what you're saying, Why check if some function failed? obviously to prevent bugs within your program, right?
let's assume realloc failed - I have some pointer to a memory that does not exist anymore or doesn't exist. If malloc fails I have a pointer to some memory that wasn't allocated - it doesn't exist, in both cases this could cause major bugs, I highly agree with you, WE SHOULD CHECK the return value, I would never program such a thing without doing so, yet I'm not trying to teach hime how to code, just to fix his bug :) @Cherubim

Comment: Agreed! Nice speaking to you. Have a great day swimming ;)